# How do I know that DispatchQueue's background processing has been terminated?

Tags: swift

I'm writing background processing in Swift.

I want to do another process when the process is complete.

```
    let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "QueueIdentification", qos: .background)
    dispatchQueue.async
    {

    }
```

How do I know that DispatchQueue's background processing has been terminated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "don't ask - tell" principle is better here:

```
  let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "QueueIdentification", qos: .background)
    dispatchQueue.async
    {
       // do whatever needed here
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
          // inform whoever needed about completion here
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you've been very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give a very slightly different formulation from Asperi's, though we are saying the same thing. You have:

```
dispatchQueue.async {

}
```

The async stuff is over when you get to the right curly brace:

```
dispatchQueue.async {

} // <-- here
```

That might not seem very helpful, because the right curly brace, although you do stop there while stepping thru the code in the debugger, is not executable. But then go back one line:

```
dispatchQueue.async {
    // ... some stuff happens ...

    // THIS is the last thing that happens; once this line runs, it's all over
}
```

So the trick is, use that last line to "know that the background processing has been terminated".